# When to change "ei" for "ie" in past tense?

Tags: word-usage, past-participle, preterite

Is there any rule, when to change "ei" into "ie" in past tense sentences ?

I know, one must change it in verbs like : `schreiben - schrieben, bleiben-blieben`. But there are also words like `begleiten - begleiteten and arbeiten - arbeiteten` which preserve the "ei" form.

Comment: The pattern seems to be stress on _ie_, followed by a voiced sound (b,d,g, h followed by a vowel). But I'm only a native speaker and have never learned this :) (_Zeigen_ seems to an exception, but that had a diphthong already in Old High German appearently...)

Comment: I think this is about strong/weak verbs, and you cannot tell whether a verb is strong or weak just by looking at the infinitive. But same here, just some native speaker :)

Comment: Another interesting case is the verb "Untersch**ei**den" and the noun "Untersch**ie**d"

Comment: @phpsgabler the rule does not work for heißen/hieß/geheißen.

Comment: @RHa */s/ /t/ /t:/ were different phonemes, s < t (eg. *hassen* "to hate") might still fit a general rule that could require to distinguish different strata. E.g. *Dussel*'s sibilant isn' t always devoiced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens with class I strong verbs. But no, there is no simple rule, you have to memorize these verbs (and the other irregular verbs too).

Comment: OK, thanks for the answer.

Comment: I'll add the data based on which I made my guess above: _speien - spie_, _schreien - schrie_, _schweigen - schwieg_, _zeihen - zieh_, _meiden - mied_, but: _zeigen - zeigte_, _leiden - litt_, _reiten - ritt_. It's a mess.